# Managing account other than salary account

Tags: income-tax, india, banking, salary, savings-account

I have a salary account in one bank and a separate saving account in other bank but i dont show my saving account details in ITR  will it affect me in future.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally it is better to give information about your other savings account. However if you are using ITR1 there is no place holder to enter the info.

More importantly when you have other savings account, any interest earned or any other income should be reported.